# OGR API: Polygon union

Tags: union, polygon, ogr

I have triangulated points, and I want to use selected triangles to prodcuce polygons.
As I use geographic coordinnates, I naturaly choose OGR to perform vector processing.

So after defining my OGRLayer (as OGRPolygon), I create for each triangles, I previously selected, a OGRPolygon (via a OGRLinearRing), and TRY to merge them in one polygon:

```
OGRPolygon ogrmerged;
for(int i=0; i<triangles.size(); i++){
    OGRLinearRing ogrring;
    ogrring.addPoint( triangles[i].a.x, triangles[i].a.y );
    ogrring.addPoint( triangles[i].b.x, triangles[i].b.y );
    ogrring.addPoint( triangles[i].c.x, triangles[i].c.y );
    ogrring.closeRings();
    OGRPolygon ogrtriangle;
    ogrtriangle.addRing( &ogrring );
    ogrmerged = *( (OGRPolygon*) ogrmerged.Union( &ogrtriangle ) );
}
```

The result is crashes or empty polygons...

Comment: What is the `merged` object (from last line `merged.union`). Is that a typo and should me `ogrmerged` or is it a different object that you haven't listed the declaration of?

Comment: Okay, well then if you are calling the OGRGeometry union (which is `Union` not `union`), then I can see one clear issue here - Union may return NULL if an error occurred. If you try to dereference NULL you are going to get a crash.

Comment: Ok, the the best is to pass by a pointer for the result and check the result before to update the ogrmerged object ?

Comment: I can't help you above checking your return value. I don't know OGR or how it reports errors. It appears from the docs that Union will return a newly allocated object OR NULL if there is an error. You will want to store the result of Union in any event, then check it for NULL. If it is not NULL, then you need to delete the old one you got back and use the new one (otherwise you will leak memory). If it is NULL then you have to figure out what error occurred. I am not sure how you go about that but the API docs should be a help.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm now using OGRGeometry pointer and apply checking after each step like : if( !newGeom->IsEmpty() && newGeom->IsValid() && (newGeom->getGeometryType() == wkbPolygon25D || newGeom->getGeometryType() == wkbPolygon){...}. It's not crashing anymore and the result is the one I expected :)

Answer (score 1):

Since `Union` returns a newly allocated object, you need to make sure the old object gets cleaned up.

```
OGRPolygon* pOgrMerged = new OGRPolygon();
for(int i=0; i<triangles.size(); i++){
    OGRLinearRing ogrring;
    ogrring.addPoint( triangles[i].a.x, triangles[i].a.y );
    ogrring.addPoint( triangles[i].b.x, triangles[i].b.y );
    ogrring.addPoint( triangles[i].c.x, triangles[i].c.y );
    ogrring.closeRings();
    OGRPolygon ogrtriangle;
    ogrtriangle.addRing( &ogrring );
    OGRPolygon* pTemp = static_cast<OGRPolygon*>(pOgrMerged->Union(&ogrtriangle));
    if (pTemp != NULL) // If you are using C++11 you could check for nullptr)
    {
        delete pOgrMerged;
        pOgrMerged = pTemp;
    }
    else
    {
        // Handle the case where the merge resulted in an error. It may be because
        // the polygons didn't overlap or something like that, check the docs for OGR
    }
}

// Do what you need to do with pOgrMerged and then return it or delete it (do not
// delete it if you are going to return it
delete pOgrMerged;
```

I know this code is using raw pointers. I don't know if you are using C++11 or not OR boost or some other library, but I would recommend wrapping the raw pointer with something like unique_ptr/shared_ptr OR if you have to auto_ptr. This way you won't leak the object.

Same code using [unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr):

```
std::uniqe_ptr<OGRPolygon> pOgrMerged(new OGRPolygon());
for(int i=0; i<triangles.size(); i++){
    OGRLinearRing ogrring;
    ogrring.addPoint( triangles[i].a.x, triangles[i].a.y );
    ogrring.addPoint( triangles[i].b.x, triangles[i].b.y );
    ogrring.addPoint( triangles[i].c.x, triangles[i].c.y );
    ogrring.closeRings();
    OGRPolygon ogrtriangle;
    ogrtriangle.addRing( &ogrring );
    OGRPolygon* pTemp = static_cast<OGRPolygon*>(pOgrMerged->Union(&ogrtriangle));
    if (pTemp != NULL) // If you are using C++11 you could check for nullptr)
    {
        pOgrMerged.reset(pTemp);
    }
    else
    {
        // Handle the case where the merge resulted in an error. It may be because
        // the polygons didn't overlap or something like that, check the docs for OGR
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah you are totaly right, I must use modern pointer which are safier that what I do. Thank you very much for you help.